# Scala Increment Counter on calling Function

Tags: function, scala, counter

How to increment a function each time its called in scala? I have a function A which performs a set of actions, when a user calls the function A, i would like to have a counter which increments and returns the counter value. The below code doesnt return the expected counter of 1 when i call it.

```
def return_id (email_user: String) : Int = {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    val count = 0
    implicit val conn = ExecuteQuery.getConnection(GENERAL_DB, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
    var idQuery=executeQuery(s"SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE email = '$email_user';")
    idQuery.first()
    val pid=idQuery.getInt("id")
    println(pid)
    if(pid != 0){
     +count = 1
    }
    return count
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala, a `val` is an immutable object and cannot be changed, whereas `var` is a variable object that CAN change. So, you can make this work by using a `var` and doing `count = count + 1`. Although the rest of the code is highly suspect, and I hope this is just a toy that you are playing with....but that is a direct answer.

Comment: Thank you @Justin Pihony, Yes this is a scratch code, I am a newbie.

Answer (score 1):

The way this code is written, it would not work correctly - your counter is inside a function and get's created and disposed on each function call, so it would always return constant value.

You need to have your counter defined outside your function block

1. One possible way to do it, using AtomicInteger

   ```
   val count = new AtomicInteger()

   def return_id (email_user: String) : Int = {
       Thread.sleep(1000)
       implicit val conn = ExecuteQuery.getConnection(GENERAL_DB, DB_USER, DB_PASS)
       var idQuery=executeQuery(s"SELECT id FROM Profile WHERE email = '$email_user';")
       idQuery.first()
       val pid = idQuery.getInt("id")
       println(pid)
       if(pid != 0){
          count.incrementAndGet()
       } else {
          count.get()
       }
   }
   ```

*count* is an AtomicInteger, to handle concurrent access.

2. The other option, more Scala way, is to have an Actor, that would handle counting for you, with 2 commands increase and get.

And many others.

Comment: Thank you @mavarazy your idea just worked, Although i have not used Akka actors as i am not familiar with it